# Why do we not have a separate conservation of angular momentum equation for fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

When deriving the governing equations, we consider conservation of mass, momentum and energy.

Why don't we consider angular momentum too? Granted it seems difficult to me how to go about writing the statement and I know that vorticity is considered, but why not a separate equation for angular momentum?

It would certainly help in simplification of many cases if we had one more equation to work with.

Comment: Which derivation? We need equations of motion for the fluid first to find what expression can we use to calculate its total energy.

Comment: I mean the standard derivations of NS energy and mass conservation in a textbook like Batchelors

Comment: What is being derived and what is being assumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include conservation of angular momentum if you wanted to, but it is directly related to conservation of momentum so there is no need to do it. You could replace momentum by angular momentum if you wanted to, of course, but including both is duplicating information. You would derive it by fixing an origin and then computing $\vec{r} \times $ the linear momentum equation.

Formally, this makes the system over-determined. So having the additional equation doesn't help you in any practical way. It doesn't provide any new information, just a different view of existing information. In practice, it wouldn't matter (in terms of a simulation, say).

There are a whole host of additional quantities that could have conservation laws written for them. Angular momentum is one, entropy is another. These additional quantities are often called "secondary conservation" quantities. In the world of numerical methods, there are efforts to ensure secondary conservation is guaranteed by the discrete scheme... it isn't always a given just because the primary quantities are conserved.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it sounds counter intuitive to me. Aren't momentum and angular momentum different quantities? Im also thinking in terms of the NS derivation in terms of the fluid element, you mean to say that the rotation is accounted for in the translation and deformation of the fluid element?

Comment: @darthcoder Those are both good questions -- they are different quantities, but they are related by a linear relationship. That means if you conserve momentum, you also conserve angular momentum for the exact Euler equations (discrete forms are a different issue due to truncation errors). As to your second question, angular momentum in the Navier-Stokes equations is conserved *iff your stress tensor is symmetric*. By construction, the viscous stress tensor is symmetric to ensure angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: The reason they are *linearly* dependent is that angular momentum $L$ is related to linear momentum $p$ by $L = r\times p$ and $r$ does not depend on $p$ -- it is simply the position vector from the origin about which angular momentum is considered to the location of the fluid volume in space.

Comment: @darthcoder No worries -- happy to help! I've spent a lot of time thinking about conservation of angular momentum in a discrete sense... numerical methods wreck a lot of the nice properties we want!